# Qt wallet equivalent in ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

What is the ethereum equivalent of Bitcoin's Qt wallet? Just bought some off of an exchange and want to store it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is official Ethereum Wallet, you can download it [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases), check the download section and choose the Ethereum-Wallet for your OS.